# deploy extra data files to deployed android app

Tags: android

Consider an app with a set of data files (could be music or pictures or locations or indeed anything at all) embedded in the apk.
I now want to provide to the user additional data files , either to replace or add to the original data files - the user should be able to select which files to download and not have to reinstall the whole app.

So the question is it possible to do this non-programmatically - like by providing extra apk files for the app but which only contain single data files?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case. A simple idea could be, ask the user to check for updates, you download a XML file which defines your updates. Parse this XML file and show what the user needs to download. Then you download and save it to desired locations. Always version the XML file so that you know if updates are avialble or not!

Comment: Thanks Royston - any thoughts on a non-programatical solution - like perhaps an APK that only consists of the new/revised data files so that an install overlays the previous installation

Comment: Yes, that would be a good solution as well! This is how market updates it APKs, a new version adding to the existing set of data files!

Comment: Problem is I make the first apk with eclipse - not sure how to make a data-only apk

Comment: A data only APK will contain files in its assets or similar folders. The APK can be as simple as, when it gets installed and run, it simply copies the contents from its asset folder to SD card.